# @Named não funciona JSF

Tags: java, jsf

Estou fazendo um projeto com jsf 2 e servidor glassfish quando coloco @Named no meu bean os atributos ficam nulos só funciona com @ManagedBean alguem já passou por esse problema

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dê uma olhada nos seus import, pode ser que esteja utilizando alguma biblioteca erroneamente ou não esteja importando algo que seja necessário.
Coloque um trecho do seu código para que possamos ajudar de maneira mais efetiva.

Answer (score 5):

Isso acontece pois a anotação `@Named` faz parte do pacote `javax.inject`, que pode ser consumida pelo JSF mas não faz parte da tecnologia em si. Use um Container Java EE completo como o [GlassFish](https://glassfish.java.net/) ou [WildFly](http://wildfly.org/) que já disponibilizam uma implementação da API de *Dependency Injection for Java* ([JSR 330](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=330)) e da CDI ([JSR 346](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=346)) para a sua aplicação. Em *containers* como o Tomcat ou Jetty você precisará disponibilizar e configurar uma implementação de CDI (como o [Weld](http://weld.cdi-spec.org/)), e, dependendo do caso, uma implementação de *Dependency Injection* (como [Google Guice](https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/)) manualmente.

Comment: Obrigado Anthony eu estou usando o glassfish, achei o problema era no meu import tinha importada a biblioteca javax.faces.bean e a correta era javax.enterprise.context obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: Opa, perfeito, aceite a resposta do nosos colega Alan então que foi quem descreveu o problema.